# Lotus Notes: Characters missing from post data

Tags: json, post, lotus-domino

I am sending to a LotusScript agent a long (300k) single-line string of urlencoded json-serialized javascript objects.

Since Domino has the limitation of 64k per text field, the json data come in chunks.

I am using this to make it a string again:

```
For i% = 0 To 999
    If docSessionContext.Hasitem("REQUEST_CONTENT_" & Format(i%, "000"))
    Then
        RequestContent = docSessionContext.Getfirstitem("REQUEST_CONTENT_" & Format(i%, "000")).Text
    Else
        Exit for
    End If
Next i%
```

As it seems, at the end of each chunk, some 130 bytes are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you concatenate the chunks like `RequestContent = RequestContent + docSessionContext.Getfirstitem(...`

Comment: old post, but... no you're not doing anything wrong. I just passed through the same. My solution was to split up the post in several posts of 32K chunks that seem to pass correctly, save them and after posting the last chunk, stitch them all together... https://stackoverflow.com/q/49009628/1195028