# POST to domino agent

Tags: lotus-domino

I want to create an attachment in Notes database (in existing document) from browser UI and I figured I will POST the data to domino agent.
I'm not really editing the doc - no Notes forms involved. In fact it's Angular UI that uses some Notes data and once I figure out that the attachment in Notes is missing I want to be able to create it.

However I'm not able to retrieve the data correctly on agent side, so I just switched to testing with Postman thus excluding any screw-up I might have in my UI code.

It looks like a Domino b-word (tried on 9.0.1FP4/9), so I just shortly describe the prob.

All goes well until Content-length of 32765. If I send 32766 bytes, the item REQUEST_CONTENT is empty. If I send 32767 bytes it contains 1 byte etc.

I played around some more - if the POST size exceeds 65273 bytes, domino starts splitting data in REQUEST_CONTENT_000, REQUEST_CONTENT_001 etc. In this case each of these blocks loose about 128 bytes. The last item might loose much more depending on size (I assume it has the same prob as the single item described above) The result is the same for both Java and LS agents. Different values for `Content-type` header does not seem to change anything.

I see a few ways out and none is fun:

1. I must assume that file upload through forms use different internal code, so I could try to simulate submit of edits, say POST to different form, retrieve attachment in WQS and move to the correct document.
2. knowing which data gets corrupted/lost in agent, I could pad my content where the data is being lost and retrieve the good data. Downside of this is that IBM (or HCL) might eventually fix the bug and then such a workaround will cause problems in turn.
3. submit series of 32765 data blocks, save them on Notes side as plain text and after the last block create the attachment.

Any other (better) ideas?

Comment: Have to ask: Are you base64-encoding the data?

Comment: yes, though the problems I describe - I just generated some random text to test why agent loose data. Once I get it through I can push real data again. I think I'm going with workaround #3

Comment: Yeah, doesn't really sound like an encoding problem anyhow. Workaround 3 sounds good, but 32765 needs to be the max size of the base64 block, so do the arithmetic to figure out what your real max is, including padding.  Also setting HTTPEnablePostDataLogging=1 might help you collect more definitive data to open a bug report with IBM, if you're planning on doing that.

Comment: thanks Richard for the ini variable, it registers all bytes I submit (so all arrive), but no indication of what might be wrong. As for base-64 and block size it does not bother me more that TCP frame size. I just cut the data in browser and stitch them together before converting back. And yes, it (#3) is working fine. No bug reports... just go on with your life